# Expressão regular para pegar a url de background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não sou muito bom ainda de expressão regular. Como é que eu poderia fazer pra capturar apenas os conteúdos presentes dentro do trecho `url()` de `background-image`?

Exemplo:

```
$elemento.css('background-image'); // "url(imagem.png)"
```

Ou então:

```
$element.css('background-image'); // "url(imagem.png), url(imagem2.png)"
```

Preciso de retornar, por Javascript puro ou jQuery, o seguinte para os casos:

```
['imagem.png']
['imagem.png', 'imagem2.png']
```

Como fazer uma expressão regular para capturar isso?

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma que funcionaria com Regex(embora o código seja deselegante) seria:

```
"url(abc.png);url(xyz.png)".match(/url\((.*?)\)/g)
        .map(function(url){ 
             return url.replace(/url\(|\)/g, "") 
        });
```

Não conheço uma forma fazer com uma única expressão.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito assim:

```js
console.log(verificaBg());

function verificaBg() {
  var arrayBg = [];
  $.each($('div'), function(key, val) {
    arrayBg[key] = $(this).css('background-image').match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1].replace(/('|")/g,'');
  });
  return arrayBg;
}
```

```css
#bg1 {
  background-image: url('http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif');
  width: 276px;
  height: 110px;
}
#bg2 {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59');
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg1"></div>
<div id="bg2"></div>
```

Comment: E quando tem dois `url()`? Por isso falei de expressão regular, pois sabia que não seria um simples replace.

Comment: @ você quer pegar todas as url's do background-image e colocar em um array ? quer fazer isso quando carregar a página ?

Comment: Sim, quero retornar todas num array. Montar um array com essas urls. Pois se tiver um, pega um. Se tiver mais de um, pega eles também.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters  como serão bg's diferentes adicionei duas div's e  2 bg's diferentes para exemplificar, da uma olhada no retorno...

Comment: acho que você não entendeu quando disse "dois atributos url()". Veja o que pode ser feito em css: `background-image: url(1.png), url(2.png), url(3.png); `. Quero retornar `['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']`

Comment: Você quer apenas a o nome  da imagem.formato  sem o caminho dela ?

Answer (score 2):

Aproveitando o exemplo postado pelo Gabriel Rodrigues.

```js
function verificaBg(id) {
  var arrayBg = [];
  var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(elemento);
  var matchs = styles.getPropertyValue("background-image").match(/\((.*?)\)/);
  
  var urls = matchs.map(function (match, indice) {
    var url = match.replace(/('|")/g,'');
    return url;
  });
  
  return urls;
}

var array = verificaBg("bg1");
console.log(array);
```

```css
#bg1 {
  background-image:
    url('http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif'),
    url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59');
  width: 276px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg1"></div>
```

Comment: este código é o melhor, porém, por que aparece duas vezes a URL uma dentro de () e uma outra separada por , sem? tem como pegar só a que está fora do parentese?

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito assim:

```
var regex = /[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]*.png/g,
    results = [],
    html = $('div').css('background-image'),
    match;

while(match = regex.exec(html)) {
    results.push(match[0]);
}

console.log(results);
```

```
<div style="background-image:url(imagem1.png), url(imagem2.png), url(imagem3.png)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Regex

```
/url\(['"][^'"]+['"]\)/g
```

#### Pluguin

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getUrlBackground = function(){
        var url = [];
        jQuery(this).each(function(){
            url[url.length] = jQuery(this).css('background-image').match(/url\(['"][^'"]+['"]\)/g);
        })
        return url;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

#### Obs

Eu não utilizaria assim. Foi apenas demonstração;

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que essa expressão regular deve resolver o problema:

```
var css = 'background-image: url(1.png), url(2.png), url(3.png),  url("3.png"),  url('3.png');'
var regex = /[^background\-image\:\s,\"\'\(\)]+[^url(.+)]+[^\"\')]/gi
```

veja funcionando aqui: **http://regexr.com/3c35n**

E aqui o exemplo, dando a saída do array:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/wzbmsy9u/**

Ou se preferir, algo mais simples, baseado somente na saída do **background-image**:

```
/([^url\(\)\,\'\"\;\s]+[A-z0-9])/
```